# Displaying all output with linebreaks in Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I am trying to show all output of a cell in my Google Colab Notebook.

I found the setting for Jupyter Notebooks which displays all of the output and not only the last line:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell

InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

However, the output is not separated by a line break which causes problem similar to the following

```
in: 
a = 3
a 
a+1 

out:
34
```

The desired output would be something more like:

```
out:
3
4
```

How can I make all distinct outputs separated by a line break? Is this possible in Jupyter Notebooks / Google Colab?

Comment: 3 years later still no solution? The lack of this feature is painful

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a print in between

```
a=3
a
print()
a+1
```

Or simply, print the two lines

```
a=3
print(a)
print(a+1)
```

Comment: this solution is ugly. there should be a better solution